# Backbone.js touch events

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

In backbone what's the best way to swap out click events for touch events.

I went down the route of using MBP.fastbutton which worked well for iOS however I am trying to move my code over to Android and need to use iScroll which doesn't seem to play nice with MBP.fastbutton.

```
initialize: function () {
    addFastButtons(this);
},

events: {
    'fastclick': 'showDetails'
},

showDetails: function (e) {
     // Do stuff
}
```

I have tried swapping out click with touchend i.e.

```
events: {
    'touchend': 'showDetails'
}
```

But this causes issues when scrolling as the app responds when the user lifts there finger, so they can jump to other pages accidentally

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the Junior code, they do this for you in their framework but you could steal the snippet to do something similar. https://github.com/justspamjustin/junior/blob/master/src/javascripts/junior.js#L3